# Spring Boot Patient Application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, url

[an image of code for some reason](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ruqQA.png)

I am trying to have a little API run. Everything runs fine but I have to make an addition and am confused. I have to have it so in the URL when I type "localhost:8080/api/v1/{illness}" it will display the names of the people with that illness...help. I have included the two classes that I have. I didn't include my patient class. It's just the constructors and getters/setters for name, gender, illness, and id. I also didn't include the main well because its not needed

```
package com.sw409.Patientdemo.controller;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PatchMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.sw409.Patientdemo.model.Patient;
import com.sw409.Patientdemo.service.PatientService;

@RestController
public class PatientController {

    PatientService patService = new PatientService();

    // CREATE
    @PostMapping("api/v1/patients")
    public Patient addPatient(@RequestBody Patient p) {
        return patService.addPatient(p);

    }
    
    //GET ILLNESS (HELP!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!)
    @PostMapping("api/v1/patients/{illness}")
    public void patientIllness() {
        return patService.patientIllness(name, illness)
    }
    

    // READ
    @GetMapping("api/v1/patients")
    public List<Patient> getPatient() {
        return patService.getPatients();

    }

    // UPDATE
    @PatchMapping("api/v1/patient/{patid}")
    public void updatePatient(@PathVariable("patid") Integer id, @RequestBody Patient p) {
        patService.updatePatient(id, p);

    }

    // DELETE
    @DeleteMapping("api/v1/patient/{patid}")
    public void deletePatient(@PathVariable("patid") Integer id) {
        patService.deletePatient(id);
    }
}
```

```
package com.sw409.Patientdemo.service;

import java.util.*;

import com.sw409.Patientdemo.model.Patient;

public class PatientService {

    List<Patient> patientList = new ArrayList<>();

    // Create
    public Patient addPatient(Patient pat) {

        patientList.add(pat);
        return pat;
    }

    public List<Patient> getPatients() {

        return patientList;
    }

    //(HELPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP)
    public void patientIllness(String illness) {
        for (int i = 0; i < patientList.size(); i++) {
            if (patientList.get(i).equals(illness){
                
            }
        }
    }

    public void updatePatient(Integer id, Patient p) {

        for (int i = 0; i < patientList.size(); i++) {

            if (patientList.get(i).getId().equals(id)) {
                patientList.set(i, p);
            }
        }
    }

    public void deletePatient(Integer id) {
        for (int i = 0; i < patientList.size(); i++) {
            if (patientList.get(i).getId().equals(id)) {
                patientList.remove(i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
package com.sw409.Patientdemo.model;

public class Patient {

    String name;
    Integer id;
    String gender;
    String illness;

    public Patient(String name, Integer id, String gender, String illness) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
        this.gender = gender;
        this.illness = illness;
    }

    public Patient() {

    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    public void setGender(String gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public String getIllness() {
        return illness;
    }

    public void setIllness(String illness) {
        this.illness = illness;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need to change your controller function to something like this:

```
@PostMapping("api/v1/patients/{illness}")
public List<Patient> patientIllness(@PathVariable String illness) {
    return patService.patientIllness(illness)
}
```

I don't understand why you called your service function with two arguments, because it can accept only one. You also need to make this function return list of patients instead of void. And illness is just a path variable, you use it in different functions, so you should understand it. And in your patient service you just need to use filter function, so it will look similiar to this:

```
public List<Patient> patientIllness(String illness) {
    return patientList.stream().filter(patient->patient.getIllness().equals(illness)).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: what is your condition part? what goes there? I cant declare the illness there. I have to use postman. add patients. and in the url use the illness to find the names of people

Comment: I edited my answer. I don't know what your Patient class looks like, but you can easily create illness getter if it does not exist yet. What do you mean you can't declare illness there? My solution uses string from url as illness.

Comment: I included the patient class. doing what you have I have the error "The method filter((<no type> patient) -> {}) is undefined for the type 
 List<Patient>"

Comment: error on filter... "The method filter((<no type> Patient) -> {}) is undefined for the type 
 List<Patient>"

Answer (score 1):

**Controller**

In case you want to get the value of something you should use GET instead of POST because POST use for creating or saving something

Your code:

```
@PostMapping("api/v1/patients/{illness}")
public void patientIllness() {
    return patService.patientIllness(name, illness)
}
```

1. The parameter is missing `patientIllness()` that's why it cannot pass the value to service
2. The return type is void so you still cannot get anything

Suggestion:

```
@GetMapping("api/v1/patients/{illness}")
public List<Patient> patientIllness(@PathVariable String illness) {
    return patService.patientIllness(illness);
}
```

1. Add paramiter in `patientIllness(String illness)` and you use it with path param so it will be `patientIllness(@PathVariable String illness)`
2. The return type should be something that you want to know if you want to know the List of Patients, return should be `List<Patient>`

**Service**

Your code:

```
public void patientIllness(String illness) {
    for (int i = 0; i < patientList.size(); i++) {
        if (patientList.get(i).equals(illness){            
        }
    }
}
```

1. The return type is void so you have change it if you want to return something to controller
2. It's worng in this code `patientList.get(i).equals(illness)` Type of `patientList.get(i)` is Patient and you compare it with String

Suggestion1:

```
public List<Patient> patientIllness(String illness) {
    List<Patient> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < patientList.size(); i++) {
        if (patientList.get(i).getIllness().equals(illness)) {
            result.add(patientList.get(i));
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

1. The return type will be `List<Patient>`
2. You should compare with the same type `patientList.get(i).getIllness().equals(illness)`

Suggestion2: you can change to for each

```
public List<Patient> patientIllness(String illness) {
    List<Patient> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Patient patient : patientList) {
        if (patient.getIllness().equals(illness)) {
            result.add(patient);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Suggestion3: You can change it to use steam, filter, and collect it to list

```
public List<Patient> patientIllness(String illness) {
    return patientList.stream()
            .filter(patient -> patient.getIllness().equals(illness))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. `patientIllness` in Controller needs a parameter `illness` to accept illness `path variable` from URL.
   Also `name` variable is not initialised (which is provided to service layer, but not used in service layer). So the `name` parameter can be removed.
2. Request mapping should be GET to retrieve data - recommended.
3. `patientIllness` in Controller should return a `List<Patient>` as received from service layer.